# Can't clone from gitlab with sourcetree macbook

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to set up my SourceTree with gitlab. I've used personal access token and it seems I'm logged in (have list of every single project from my company). But when I'm trying to clone one of them I have an error:

'abort: repository git@gitlab.com:xxx/xxx/xxx-v2.git not found!'

Already have cleared gitlabs credentials - didn't help.

Any ideas how to deal with it?

Comment: Is this repository public? If not are you sure you have access right to it? Are you sure you didn't mistyped Url?

Comment: @MarekR it's private, but I do have access to this - it works pretty good on windows device, where I'm using tortoise git, but here with Sourcetree it doesn't..